# How to "snip"/extract part of a C char[] (memory address) as a python string

Tags: python, c, gdb

For writing a [pretty printer for GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Selecting-Pretty_002dPrinters.html#Selecting-Pretty_002dPrinters) I have a structure that contains a memory address (recognized as `unsigned char *` by GDB) and a size field.

While it was easy to extract those and write those out as-is I struggle how to actually handle the data as a char array instead of a string. When returning the address as-is GDB will output the data on the address as C-string (null-terminated) while the memory buffer is not a C string (it may contain a NULL within size or not.

I *guess* I may need to copy the data with the given size to a python buffer and operate on this instead - but I have no clue how to do that (or obviously, what to search for).

That's what I've got so far (only [working] checks and an otherwise "plain" gdb output):

```py
# include with 
#   python execfile("myprinter.py")

class MyPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string (self):
        size = self.val['size']
        buffer = self.val['data']
        
        if (size == 0):
            return "-zero length-"
        if (data == 0):
            return "-no data-"
      
        #return "<size={0:d}> at ???: {1:{0}.{0}}".format(size, data)
        #return "<size={0:d}>: {1}".format(size, data)
        return self.val

def display_hint(self):
    return 'mytype'

def lookup_type (val):
    if str(val.type) == 'mytype':
        return MyPrinter(val)
    return None

gdb.pretty_printers.append (lookup_type)
```

With the result of:

```
(gdb) p typo_123
typo_123 = <size=12>: 0x7fe5c21b50b0 ' ' <repeats 200 times>...
```

where it should be:

```
(gdb) p typo_123
typo_123 = <size=12> at 0x7fe5c21b50b0: "            "
```

**Question**: How can I handle the C memory address as integer (printed as hex for "at ???") and convert it to a python string with a given fixed length?

Comment: Look at `libstdcxx/v6/printers.py`, it has code like `return ptr.string (length = length)`.

Comment: While I see that code in https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py I fail to see how to apply that (and get cast errors if I try something similar=, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Actually the comment above looks correct. Perhaps (if you still have the code...?) you can show your attempt and the full error message